# Opening php files shows a lot of blank lines, how do I correctly fix their appearance

Tags: php, notepad++, newline, notepad, carriage-return

I'm opening some php files that were originally made by someone else and then some other person has edited them and now when I open them they appear extremley messy because or the \r and \n messes.

How do I correctly fix the newlines...

See the following screenshot for an example of one part:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/r1a9PvW.png]

I've had this problem with serveral files in the past and manually gone through and changed the newlines manually to make them "pretty" for my eyes but would love to know how to fix it for good...

I assume it's a linux vs windows problem...

Comment: Couldn't you just remove all lines that only contain newlines (search+replace or php `preg_replace` and manually fix the rest. Should atleast remove most of the work

Comment: It's more than just one file to "fix" and of course it can be done manually like that but I'm looking for a permanent fix for it...

Comment: You could try using one of these tools: https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=php+code+formatter

Comment: Do your editors not allow you to select what line endings to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `(\R)\1+`
Replace with: `$1`

Where `\R` stands for any of `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`.
This  will replace 2 or more line break, no matter what it is, by only one.

Comment: Would `(\R)+` replaced with `$1` be better where sequences such as `\n` `\r\n` `\n` might occur?

Comment: @JonM: You're right, but it's strange to have several kind of line break in a file.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried another IDE? on notepadd++ you could just copypaste and replace the code with an empty space

Comment: Which ones do you suggest and what do you mean "copypaste and replace the code with an empty space"

I kinda fix it "fix" it by replacing `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n` with nothing but then other parts have less to replace, it still looks messy in other places

Comment: i mean you can copy CRLF then go on search->replace and then use the option replace all with an empty space